# How to split an URL without use the .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing

some time ago I use a small php mvc framework. This framework works using the .htaccess file. In the .htaccess I use some rules to take the url and pass it through parameters at my index.php file, like this:

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 9999

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fba/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Later in my index.php I use the url parameter to split the url and instantiate the Controller and the method to invoke. For example if the url is something like `myserver.com/User/getAll` this will instantiate the controller User and invocate the getAll method. But now I'm working in a server that has disabled  the .htaccess file, and I can't change it. There is some alternative to the use of the .htaccess file, do the splitting of the url in some php file maybe?

If you want to see the full code of this framework you can check [here](http://static.jream.com/lab/mvc/mvc.tutorial.part.11.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. You could refer to the main index.php and add variables:

```
index.php?url=User-getAll
```

Keeping the links as they are, will not work, as the server does not know that you want all the links to refer to the index.php.

Comment: Well thanks, it's not exactly what I was hoping found, but I did something like you said: I use `meserver.com/controller/SomeController.php?method="foo"&clazz="AppleController"`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your actual architecture and needs, but alternative solution may be something like overwriting the routing:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['action'])) { 
        include 'controllers/' . check_filename($_GET['a']) . '.php';
    }
    if (isset($_GET['view'])) { 
        include 'views/'.check_filename($_GET['v']) . '.php';
    }

?>
```